# regex string end with .log and contains chars numbers and -

Tags: regex

Can someone tell me the regex pattern to match everything that ends with .log and contains chars, numbers and -

for example:
"syslog-12-10-2011.log"

Comment: Are you verifying that the string matches the pattern, or looking for the pattern in a larger string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regex that you can use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.log$
```

Comment: You do not need to escape the dash in square brackets with a backslash .

Comment: @AdamZalcman Don't need it but I like to escape it because I like to reuse the code. So if I would edit this regex I've not to check again all the unescaped chars.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
^[a-z0-9-]+\.log$
```

Comment: If you weren't anchored, I'd vote you up. Anchoring is only correct if verifying a string, but we don't know that that's what is going on.

Comment: Alas, it seems that the thing required to make it perfect (an end-of-word anchor) is not defined by the POSIX RE spec, so we're into the domain of extensions and we don't know which exact dialect is being used.

Answer (score 3):

The regexp you're looking for is

```
^[A-Za-z0-9-]*\.log$
```

note that dot requires escaping and dash must be the first or last character inside square brackets (otherwise it denotes character range).

Note that this matches filename '.log'. Replace the star with a plus to have it match filenames with at least one character before the dot in '.log'.

Answer (score 1):

With a case insensitive regular expression:

```
^[A-Z]+-([0-9]{2}-){2}[0-9]{4}\.log$
```

It's a bit more precise than what you asked (it matches text-nn-nn-nnnn.log, where n is a digit). If you are using POSIX regex (like in `grep` for instance), you will have to escape parenthesis and brackets:

```
[A-Z]+-\([0-9]\{2\}-\)\{2\}[0-9]\{4\}\.log$
```